# Why can I not use tensorflow-gpu even after I have succeed in installing cuda 9.2?

Tags: tensorflow

I have followed many tutorials to install the cuda + tensorflow-gpu to accelerate the machine learning calculations, but failed.

I have installed the VS2017 like this

[image]

After that I install the CUDA 9.2 since my gpu shows that it supports the CUDA9.2 like below:

[image].

It seems that everything is ok when I install CUDA, I also copy the cudnn to the CUDA folder and add the folder to the systems path on windows 10, the command nvcc and devicequery.exe can both execute successfully like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does it mean I succeed installing cuda on windows 10?

However, when I use tensorflow-gpu with Python 3.5 it show that error

```
import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Robbon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Robbon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Robbon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Robbon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Robbon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Robbon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Robbon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Robbon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Robbon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Robbon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Robbon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Robbon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Robbon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。
```

I find all the method I can find to fix this problem but it is no help. I can import tensorflow when I use tensorflow rather than tensorflow-gpu.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your tensorflow-gpu version and see if it follows the cuDNN and CUDA version listed at [Tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).

The official install guide is recommended.

[Install TensorFlow with pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

And my first successful install followed this guide.

[Thanks to Phil Ferriere](https://github.com/philferriere/dlwin)

Comment: Thanks, I have solved this problem by retrying the installing process with VStudio 2015, it seems that python 3.5 do not support CUDA 9.2 ?? I can succeed with CUDA 9.0, but fail when i use CUDA 9.2 with the comment "lack of CUDA 9.0 runtime lib" or some comments like this..